# How to authenticate multiple hosts using selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to run tests against a website that requires four different sets of basic auth.  There is all sorts of content embedded in the site requiring separate auth.  For example:

```
http://store.domain.com
http://content.domain.com
https://content.domain.com
https://store.domain.com
```

Another way to say this is that when I hit one URL, I get four different sets of auth pop ups.

I'm not sure how to tackle this via Selenium.  I currently have a working test written in Python / Selenium Web Driver, but when I run it I am forced to manually keep entering in creds each time, which is not a viable solution as this is going to be run from a TC build on a remote server.

Since it seems like Selenium isn't very flexible with auth stuff, I thought maybe as I workaround I could just hit each of the URLs requesting auth, pass them creds (this would happen during setup), and then start the actual tests.  I need help with this for multiple reasons.

```
class newSmokeTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://domain.com"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True
        driver = self.driver

        # sending auth credentials early to avoid prompts while running test suite
        driver.get("http://username:pass@store.domain.com")
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        driver.get("https://username:pass@store.domain.com")
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        driver.get("http://username:pass@content.domain.com")
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        driver.get("https://username:pass@content.domain.com")

    def test1(self):
        #do stuff

    def test2(self):
        #do stuff
```

One, I'm not even sure if that is a viable solution, would manually passing creds to each URL in the setup of my unittest create a session in Firefox, how do I find that out?

Two, when I run the test, I actually don't visually see the browser hitting those URL's.  Is putting those steps in the setUp for some reason preventing those steps from running?

I'm kind of at a dead end with this, would appreciate any help.  Using a Firefox profile is not the answer I'm looking for as this will be ran on a remote server by another department and I'm not even sure that they would allow the installation of a Firefox profile on there.  Hoping I can do this in a more Pythonic way.

Comment: what do you mean by popup?

it sounds like the site your are testing is not ready for testing and you need to tell the devs this.

Comment: I mean basic authentication, in which Chrome or Firefox produces a pop up requesting username or password, if failed it results in a 401 Unauthorized page.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. You can't interact with client-generated dialogs (like JS alerts, Basic Auth dialogs, and File Upload dialogs) via Selenium unfortunately. However, you can perform Basic Auth in a URL via the `proto://user:pass@host/path` format. E.g. `http://bob:pizza@yahoo.com/mysite`

Comment: Just to be clear, it IS basic auth, the issue is that there is basic auth for not just the website, but the content embedded on the website, which results in multiple basic auth requirements just to view a single page.  When I say the browser produces the pop up, I literally mean the browser (the popup is not produced by the website).

Comment: I don't know a way around this, but it seems to me that something is just wrong with that website. I'm thinking if there's a way to change the urls in the embedded content to include user:pass@site to do the basic auth implicitly. 

Hmm. If you could capture the urls of the embedded content, you could try loading them manually at the beginning of the selenium script, loading them with user:pass@site (just insert the right user:pass into the urls and use browser.get() on them one by one). The browser should retain the credentials and the embedded content should then load without issue.

Comment: Mind you not every single embedded element but just one from each endpoint / site that causes the popup. Needs to happen within one/each test though. Perhaps in a "before test" method. It needs to happen without the browser closing before the test.